# 2 way smart contract exchange

Tags: contract-development, tokens

Need a smart contract to exchange ERC20 for Ether and Ether for ERC20.

The goal is, you send ether you get erc20, you send erc20 you get ether back. Without having to use web3 tools.

The only way I can think for implementation is to use the ERC20 itself as exchange contract.

Then the token address will have to hold both ether and its own tokens.

This sounds like bad practice, or is it? Any better idea to achieve that?

Comment: Not sure if this is actually doable without web3 tools (to pass method parameters) and some sort of Oracle (if the price of the token is dynamic).

Comment: Mate, where you able to build this one?

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly combine them, but I think it makes more sense to have a second contract. That way the ERC20 token contract stays simple and focused on just the token interface.

The contract doing the selling just needs two functions that deal with the token contract. In pseudocode, ignoring error checking, etc.

```
buyTokens():
    howMany = msg.value / pricePerToken * 10**decimals
    tokenContract.transfer(msg.sender, howMany)

sellTokens(howMany):
    // Caller will need to first approve() that many tokens
    tokenContract.transferFrom(msg.sender, howMany * 10**decimals)

    msg.sender.transfer(howMany * pricePerToken)
```

Comment: the idea was to make it simple for user just to send tokens to the sell address. With the sellTokens above sounds like user need to web3 to pass the parameter.

Comment: To transfer tokens to an address, some tools has to be used that knows how to pass parameters. If you want to piggyback on the existing `transfer(address,uint256)` function in an ERC20 token, then you would indeed need to put special code in there. ERC223 calls a `tokenFallback` in function if the destination is a smart contract... you could perhaps implement that or something like it..